# How to plot contour from points coordinate in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an image and four points (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4). They are pixel coordinates of image. I want to generate one contour from points around image using Matlab. I try to make it but it does not accuracy. Which does implement better?

```
X=[x1 x2 x3 x4];
Y=[y1 y2 y3 y4];
BW1 = roipoly(I,X,Y); % I is an image
figure, 
imagesc(uint8(I),[0 255]),colormap(gray);axis equal;axis off;
hold on,[c1,h1] = contour(BW1,[0 0],'r','linewidth',1.4); hold off
```

Comment: Sorry - but your difficulty with English is getting in the way of my understanding. "One contour from there points". Can you show what you want this contour to look like? Is it a polygon? Or four contours corresponding to the pixel intensity at four points in the image? Not clear… Please expand your question so we may help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are trying to do (I am guessing here…):

```
X=[x1 x2 x3 x4];
Y=[y1 y2 y3 y4];
BW1 = roipoly(I,X,Y); % I is an image
figure
imagesc(uint8(I),[0 255])
colormap(gray);
axis equal;axis off;
hold on;
plot([X X(1)], [Y Y(1)], 'r', 'linewidth', 1.4); % <<<<< using plot instead of contour
```

or perhaps you need

```
[c1,h1] = contour(BW1,[0 0] + 0.5,'r','linewidth',1.4); hold off
```

This second case uses the fact that a contour of 0.5 will sit right on the boundary between 0 and 1, as needed. But I suspect that your `BW1` image will overwrite the original image… sorry can't test right now and you left a lot to be guessed.